# Finding vector length for high dimensions

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

How do I find the vector length for high dimensions?.We can find vector length for 3d with the formula $\sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2+v_3^2}$
Likewise how to find the vector magnitude for high dimensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way:$$\bigl\|(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\bigr\|=\sqrt{{x_1}^2+{x_2}^2+\cdots+{x_n}^2}.$$This is the usual norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thanks sir.But in higher dimensions the axes wont be orthogonal to each other.Is this correct?

Comment: @aneeshcool No, it is not.

Comment: Can you please explain it.iam new.In 3d the axes willl be orthogonal so this formula can be applied but in higher dimensions how will the axes be orthogonal to each other?

Comment: @aneeshcool In order for me to answer your question, please tell me: how do you define “orthogonal”?

Comment: it means perpendicularly

Comment: @aneeshcool Then tell me: how do you define “perpendicular”?

Comment: When the angle between two lines or axes is 90° sir

Comment: Its just my intuitions sir.Vector length is calculated based on Pythagoras theorem.Pythagoras theorem can be applied to right angle triangle only.So in 2d and 3d they are perpendicular so we can apply Pythagoras theorem to calculate vector length.How is it possible to calculate vector length in higher dimensions?.Please correct me if iam wrong

Comment: @aneeshcool In order to talk about angles of $90^\circ$, we must be able to measure them. In $\mathbb{R}^n$, the usual way of measuring the angle $\theta$ between two vectors $v=(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ and $w=(w_1,\ldots,w_n)$ is:$$\cos\theta=\frac{v_1w_1+\cdots+v_nw_n}{\sqrt{{v_1}^2+\cdots+{v_n}^2}\sqrt{{w_1}^2+\cdots+{w_n}^2}}.$$With this definition, the axes *are* orthogonal.

Comment: Sorry sir iam not able to clearly understand the formula.

Comment: @aneeshcool DO you know what $\cos\theta$ means?

Comment: I know cos theta sir.But I can't clearly understand the formula amidst the "$" and other signs.I mean its not readable

Comment: @aneeshcool Are you using Android?

Comment: Yes sir.Iam using from my android

Comment: @aneeshcool I use it too. Click on my comment and then, on the upper right corner, click on the list of options (a vertical row of dots). Then choose “Render MathJax”.

Comment: Thanks sir.Now I understood.But I can't visualise those higher dimensions where the axes are orthogonal.

Comment: @aneeshcool Neither can I. But I can compute angles and lengths using the formulas that I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation sir.But only when we can visualise we can check if the formula is right or wrong

Answer (score 1):

As a side answer, since the OP do not understand how "orthogonal in high dimensions" can be represented...

Well, it is normal. We are living in a seemingly 3D spatial dimensions world, so we can easily represent ourselves in such a space, and understand concepts with parallels in this 3D spatial world.

However, it is, for our brain, much more difficult to have a spatial representation of something in 4D, 5D etc. This is why we are using more formalism in order to be able to go beyond the limits of our perception.

Imagine you are a kind of microscopic worm living at the surface of a giant leaf. For you, everything is in 2D (remember that ourselves we believed that the earth - not our entire world - was 2D at some point in time, because when you are at the surface, you don't seeit otherwise). You can go forward, left, right, backward, but that's it... You don't know if there are other dimensions, and, should you have a brain caable of abstract thought, it would nevertheless be puzzling to think spatially about a space in 3D.

When you want to do higher level mathematics (and in particular geometry), you need to distance yourself in a certain extent to the notions you gained with analogies with the real world. I say to a certain extent, for doing parallels to the 3D case sometimes can bring sometimes insight about a problem (and sometimes it is misleading).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation sir.